# Create a collection with users - my javacode ok?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Im using java/mongodb. I would like to create a table (collection) with some users. Well, its working im just not sure about my coding style. Could be this good if i just want to add 3 new persons to the collection?

```
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
    doc.put("name", "klaus");
    doc.put("age", 30);
    doc.put("city", "new york");
    col.insert(doc);

    BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc2.put("name", "mirko");
    doc2.put("age", 23);
    doc2.put("city", "madrid");
    col.insert(doc2);

    BasicDBObject doc3 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc3.put("name", "jon");
    doc3.put("age", 34);
    doc3.put("city", "unknown");
    col.insert(doc3);
```

Its look so "long". To add only 3 Persons I have to create **always** a new BasicDBObject and insert it with the same line code (col.insert(bla))? It cant be ^^ And an other question too: At the first time(doc) im adding name, age and city as column. Why do I have to add "name", "age" and "city" again and again... I just want to add "mirko", 23 and "madrid" for doc2.

The last thing what bugs me is that I can add a new Dokument to the Collection with the same(!) values. I could add a new jon with 34 years and the same city. Is this ok? And if yes, I would like to change it. Howto?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json for it..

```
String json = "{'key' : 'value'}"; /* Create json formatted data here */

DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);

collection.insert(dbObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to execute insert several times. You can make one insert call for collection of objects:

[http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert(java.util.List)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert%28java.util.List%29)

For example:

```
 List<BasicDBObject> docs = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

 BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
    doc.put("name", "klaus");
    doc.put("age", 30);
    doc.put("city", "new york");
    docs.add(doc);

    BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc2.put("name", "mirko");
    doc2.put("age", 23);
    doc2.put("city", "madrid");
    docs.add(doc2);

    BasicDBObject doc3 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc3.put("name", "jon");
    doc3.put("age", 34);
    doc3.put("city", "unknown");
    docs.add(doc3);

    col.insert(docs);
```

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/),a java library, for MongoDB. It lets you save, retrieve and update POJO objects as documents.

For your second query related to collections with same values, in mongoDB you have the option to use unique indexes which makes sure no two records of same values are inserted in the collection